# Angular2 directive not working

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use a simple directive according to video tutorial. I dont know why, my code does not affect text color. Can somebody help me? Here's code:

app.component.html:

```
   <p colorer>textTMP</p>
```

app.component.ts:

```
    import { Colorer } from './colorer.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    providers: [ Colorer],
})
export class AppComponent{}
```

colorer.service.ts:

```
    import { Input, Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
    selector: '[colorer]',
    host: {
        '(mouseenter)': 'color()'
    }
})

export class Colorer {
    constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {}

    color() {
        this._el.nativeElement.style.color = 'red';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A directive is not a service. You can't inject it as a provider. You need to declare it in your module along with your component.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
      BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, Colorer ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

See the [Plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/ntXlwpruJW7QuD9M30cF?p=preview) that illustrates this.